# How to add single quotes around columns using awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Just wondering how can I add single quotes around fields, so I can import it to mysql without warnings or errors.

I have a csv file with lots of content.

```
16:47:11,3,r-4-VM,250000000.,0.50822578824,131072,0,0,0,0,0
```

Desired output

```
'16:47:07','3','r-4-VM','230000000.','0.466028518635','131072','0','0','0','60','0'
```

I really have no idea where to start, your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

You could try this

```
awk -F"," -v quote="'" -v OFS="','" '$1=$1 {print quote $0 quote}' file
```

1. Replace each separator (, comma) with (',' quote-comma-quote) -> `(-F"," -v OFS="','")`
2. Add quotes to the begin and end of line -> `(print quote $0 quote)`

Comment: The `$1=$1` idiom confused me, but Google found an explanation for me.  By assigning to even one field you force AWK to rebuild the whole line, thus changing the original field separator to the new one.  http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/

Answer (score 2):

`awk` and `sed` are not going to (easily) determine whether the field separator (`,`) is escaped or not. The csv file format escapes `,` characters within fields by surrounding the whole field in double quotes (see Section 2.6 of [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2)).

As I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60618482/3697870), a more robust method is to use a csv library, rather than parsing as text using regular expressions and the like.

I found Python's library was the best choice because it's:

1. widely available without onerous dependencies, with the exception of Python itself;
2. not particular sensitive to the version of Python you use;
3. lends itself to being embedded within a shell script; and
4. is quite compact (a one-liner will do!).

Based on the question's tags, I suspect these criteria will be appealing to you too.

Thus, try the following:

```
QUOTE_CSV_PY="import sys; import csv; csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar=\"'\").writerows(csv.reader(sys.stdin))"
python -c "$QUOTE_CSV_PY" < file
```

To break it down:

- `QUOTE_CSV_PY` is a shell variable containing the Python one-liner commands
- The Python commands simply:

  - import the standard sys and csv modules;
  - create a csv writer that writes to standard output (`stdout`) with `QUOTE_ALL` set so all fields get quoted using `quotechar`, which is set to a single quote;
  - feed the csv writer a csv reader that reads from standard input (`stdin`).
- The second line simply passes the one-liner to the python interpreter, and feeds the csv file (called `file`) into its `stdin`.

Comment: That solution is particularly useful as it covers the case where a field with an embedded comma has quotes around it, which few people consider

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=OFS=","}

{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        $i = "'" $i "'"
    print
}
```

At the beginning, set `FS` (the field separator) to a comma; also set `OFS`, the output field separator, to a comma.

For every input line, loop over all fields.  `NF` is the number of fields parsed out of the current line.  Set each field to its own value surrounded by single quotes.

When done updating the fields, print the modified line.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
awk '{gsub(/^|$/,"\x027");gsub(/,/,"\x027,\x027")}7' file
```

example

```
kent$  echo "16:47:11,3,r-4-VM,250000000.,0.50822578824,131072,0,0,0,0,0"|awk '{gsub(/^|$/,"\x027");gsub(/,/,"\x027,\x027")}7'
'16:47:11','3','r-4-VM','250000000.','0.50822578824','131072','0','0','0','0','0'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[^,]+/'\''&'\''/g' file
```

or:

```
sed -r "s/[^,]+/'&'/g" file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i)  $i="~"$i"~"}{print}' $input_csv_file
```

This works. Here I am enclosing all the csv file columns with a `~`.