# Bash How to wrap values of the first line of a csv file with quotations, if they do not exist

Tags: bash, csv, if-statement, quotations

The other day I asked how to wrap values of the first line of a csv file with quotations. I was given this reply which worked great.

```
$ cat file.csv  
word1,word2,word3,word4,word5  
12345,12346,12347,12348,12349
```

To put quotes around the items in the first line only:

```
$ sed '1 { s/^/"/; s/,/","/g; s/$/"/ }' file.csv  
"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"  
12345,12346,12347,12348,12349
```

I now need to test if the quotes exist around the values to eliminate chances of double quoting values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem suits awk more than `sed` due to row/column processing:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1 {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {gsub(/^"|"$/, "", $i); $i = "\"" $i "\""}
} 1' file

"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"
12345,12346,12347,12348,12349
```

- Using `gsub` function we remove leading or trailing double quote, if it exists
- Then we can safely wrap each cell in double quotes

Comment: This one worked great. I even placed  quotes at random values like so:  

    `word1,word2,"word3",word4,"word5"`  

and the final output was always  

    `"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"`

Answer (score 3):

Change each of the substitutions to include optional quotes:

```
sed -E '1 { s/^"?/"/; s/"?,"?/","/g; s/"?$/"/ }' file.csv
```

I have added `-E` to enable extended mode, so that `?` is understood to mean "0 or 1 match".

You could also keep on using basic mode (no `-E`) and replace each `?` with either `\{0,1\}` (again, 0 or 1 match) or `*` (which matches 0 or more).

Comment: Tom this command suits me best. If the values were missing the quotes and if some of them had it, they were skipped so first lines like `word1,"word2","word3","word4",word5`  or `word1,word2,word3,word4,word5` always became `"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"`.  You guys were very helpful. I surely appreciate all the help!

Comment: Alas, this fails if a quoted field has a comma. Eg. `one,"two,two",three` becomes `"one","two","two","three"`.

Comment: You're right, @Heath, and there are probably many other inputs that would cause it to fail, after all it's just a series of substitutions that aren't context-aware. The best way to process a CSV file is to use a tool that supports them, such as Python with its [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: Funny, using Python's `csv` module (from within a shell script) is indeed what I ended up doing. I'll add my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions with `sed` and `awk` are subject to a seemingly never-ending series of edge cases that fail. Leveraging a csv library instead provides a great deal more robustness.

I found Python's library was the best choice because it's:

1. widely available without onerous dependencies, with the exception of Python itself;
2. not particular sensitive to the version of Python you use;
3. lends itself to being embedded within a shell script; and
4. is quite compact (a one-liner will do!).

Thus, my solution is along the lines of:

```
QUOTE_CSV_PY='import sys; import csv; csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL).writerows(csv.reader(sys.stdin))'
head -1 file.csv | python -c "$QUOTE_CSV_PY"; tail -n +2 file.csv
```

To break it down:

- `QUOTE_CSV_PY` is a shell variable containing the Python one-liner commands
- The Python commands simply import the standard `sys` and `csv` modules. It then creates a csv writer that writes to `stdout` with `QUOTE_ALL` set so all fields get quoted. It is fed a csv reader that reads from `stdin`.
- `head -1` sends the first line to the python interpreter for processing.
- `; tail -n +2` waits until the processing is done and then just dumps out every line from number two onwards.

Comment: Nice, the only thing I would say is that `"$QUOTE_CSV_PY"` should be quoted when you use it (it has no nasty side-effects here, but could with other scripts).

Comment: Quite right. I errantly dropped the quotes while transcribing. Fixed.

Comment: nice - as you said - this is much more robust, and can be easily extended too :D !

Answer (score 0):

Keep your existing working sed command, by removing all possible double quotes first:

```
sed '1 { s/"//g; s/^/"/; s/,/","/g; s/$/"/ }' file.csv
```

Comment: This was close. If the values had quotes already, everything was left the same except the last value which had a space before the closing quotation like so:

    `"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5 "`

Answer (score 0):

To test each answer I created three files:

**file.csv**

```
word1,word2,word3,word4,word5  
12345,12346,12347,12348,12349
```

**file2.csv**

```
"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"  
12345,12346,12347,12348,12349
```

**file3.csv**

```
"word1",word2,word3,"word4",word5  
12345,12346,12347,12348,12349
```

Then I created a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash  

sed -E '1 { s/^"?/"/; s/"?,"?/","/g; s/"?$/"/ }' file.csv > final.csv  
sed -E '1 { s/^"?/"/; s/"?,"?/","/g; s/"?$/"/ }' file2.csv > final2.csv  
sed -E '1 { s/^"?/"/; s/"?,"?/","/g; s/"?$/"/ }' file3.csv > final3.csv
```

Then I looked at the final files and the first lines were perfect.

```
# cat final*.csv  

"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"  
12345,12346,12347,12348,12349  
"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"  
12345,12346,12347,12348,12349  
"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"  
12345,12346,12347,12348,12349
```